How do I update a version number for a Github Action I host
I host a GitHub Action that other projects use. I need to update it (to use Node 20, not Node 16, but that's beside the point).
I want to revise the version number of my github action, from richb-hanover/cargo@1.1.0 (which currently works fine) to richb-hanover/cargo@1.1.1 to indicate there's a new version.
I edited the package.json file to use version: '1.1.1'. But my test runs all display messages like the one below. How can I fix this? Many thanks.
Unable to resolve action `richb-hanover/cargo@v1.1.1`, unable to find version `v1.1.1`


They're discovered by refs - how was v1.1.0 published, maybe branch name or tag? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions#using-release-management-for-actions

@jonrsharpe - I did this many years ago - I have no memory of how it was published. How could I tell? (That link doesn't give much info). Many thanks!

You can look in your repo: https://github.com/richb-hanover/cargo/branches, https://github.com/richb-hanover/cargo/tags

I found the answer to my question. The act of making a new version of an action available is called "publishing an action to Github Marketplace". (That's why I asked such a broad question initially - I didn't know the right search terms...)
The process is described at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/publishing-actions-in-github-marketplace
